# Using Variables with react-apollo Query

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-tag

I've attached a query to my React Native component like so:

```
let getNearbyStoriesQuery = gql`{
  getStoriesNearbyByGeoHash(geoHash: "8k"){
      id
  }
}`;

export default graphql(getNearbyStoriesQuery,
  {
    props: (props) => {
      debugger;
      let storiesNearby = props.data.getStoriesNearbyByGeoHash.map((story) => {
        return {
          id: story.id,
        }
      });
      return {storiesNearby};
    },
    variables: {
      geoHash: mockGeoHash
    }
  })(Home);  // Home is the React Native Component
```

I'm able to retrieve data from using this technique as long as I hardcode a value in for geoHash in the query; in this case I used "8k".  However, when I attempt to modify the query so that I can puss in a variable like so:

```
let getNearbyStoriesQuery = gql`{
      getStoriesNearbyByGeoHash($geoHash: String!){
          id
      }
    }`;
```

I get an error saying `Expected Name, found $`.  This method of passing variables to queries is repeated across multiple sources.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
query GetStoriesNearbyByGeoHash($geoHash: String!) {
    getStoriesNearbyByGeoHash(geoHash: $geoHash){
         id
    }
}
```

Have a look on how to use variables in graphql: http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy for a few hours.